# Search items from a List box using Search box

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, search-box

I have a ListBox in which I am having large list of data. I want to search for items in this list using the SearchBox so that as per the text entered in the SearchBox the list of items in the ListBox should be altered accordingly.
I looked on the internet but could not find any examples of how to do it.
Your help/suggestions will be much appreciated.
here is my XAML

```
        <SearchBox 
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Height="50" 
        Margin="10,0,10,10"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <ListBox
            x:Name="lbSkills"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Margin="10,0,10,10" SelectionChanged="lbSkills_SelectionChanged">
                <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
                    </Style>
                </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="Beige">
                            <Grid Width="auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="26" Grid.Column="0" Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding SkillDescription}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a textbox, a button, and a listbox or DataGrid.

You connect the textbox to your viewmodel property. Connect the button to your viewmodel command property. Connect the listbox or datagrid source to an observable list property on the viewmodel. Run a linq search query when the button is executed and have it fill the observable list.

If you need code specific solution, send a comment.

---

Update 1:

Link to a sample project with Search implemented
https://mahowling.wordpress.com/2014/07/31/wpf-search-text-box-for-mvvm/

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the bound collection of List through `CollectionView`. 
Your implementation can be  as follows :
Define the TextChanged handler;  Get `CollectionView` for `ListBox's ItemsSource` and define the `filter` delegate. You can store as the `CollectionView` member variable so that you don't need to get the CollectionView again and again

```
private void txtSearchFilter_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ICollectionView items = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lbSkills.ItemsSource);
            if (items != null)
            {
                items.Filter = SearchFilter;
            }
        }


public bool SearchFilter(object filterObject)
        {
           var filter = filterObject as <<List Box item type>>;
            if (filter == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

             <<Your search logic here.......>>        
}
```

Since, text Changed event fires on each key stroke so you can implement do delay search. You can follow the [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20068/Custom-TextBox-that-Delays-the-TextChanged-Event) article to implement that.

Comment: hi sorry for the delayed reply, but what is filterobject here? and where are we filtering the List?

Comment: The `SearcFilter` is a predicate handler which will be invoked by `Filter` predicate to filter the ListBox. Definition of  `Predicate<object> Filter { get; set; }`. So when `SearchFilter` is invoked then filterObject will be of type of bound ListBox ItemSource item type.